# presentation for GL(n,K)

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices

let $K$ be a field, $n \geq 1$. denote $E_{i,j}$ the elementary matrix having $1$ on the diagonale and in the entry $(i,j)$, and $E_i(a)$ the elementary matrix $diag(1,...,a,...,1)$. you know that $GL_n(K)$ is generated by these matrices, but what relations do we need in order to get a presentation for $GL_n(K)$?

here are some relations, which correspond to simple relations about row operations:

- $E_i(1)=1$
- $E_i(ab) = E_i(a) E_i(b)$
- $E_i(a) E_j(b) = E_j(b) E_i(a)$
- $(E_j(-1) E_{ij})^2=1$
- $E_j(a+b)^{-1} E_{ij} E_j(a+b) = E_j(a)^{-1} E_{ij} E_j(b) E_i(a)^{-1} E_{ij} E_j(a)$
- $ (E_{ji} E_{ij} E_{ji} E_j(-1))^2=1$

are these all relations? how can we prove that?

EDIT: Mariano has given a counterexample when $K = \mathbb{F}_2$. well, how can we fix this? add more relations? incorporate the structure of $K$ as a ring? what about concrete examples such as $K=\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: One way of getting a presentation for a Lie group is exponentiating a presentation from the Lie algebra. For the Lie algebra, the presentation will not be hard to do (just take the Cartan subalgebra, $e_{i,i+1}$, and $e_{i+1,i}$), and you can work out the relations for them. It is not necessary to use the matrices corresponding to all $(i,j)$-s - that might overcomplicate things. 

Comment: It seems to me that this should be a presentation of the simply connected form of the Lie group. But GL_2(R) is not simply connected: the universal cover is basically the metaplectic group. I could imagine much worse things could happen with nonarchimedean fields, but I don't know.

Comment: Heh. Is $\mathbb F_2$ not concrete? :)

Comment: can you give a presentation for $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$?

Comment: See Steinberg, Lectures on Chevalley groups. For $n=2$ extra relations are needed. This is related to David's comment.

Answer (score 11):

This is a sideways answer.

Let $E_{ij}(a)=I+a E_{ij}$, for $i\neq j$ and $a\in A$.These matrices generate the conmutator subgroup $$E(n, A)=[\mathrm{GL}(n, A),\mathrm{GL}(n, A)]\subseteq\mathrm{GL}(n, A).$$
One can easily check that the obvious relations satisfied by these elements are $$E_{ij}(a)E_{ij}(b)=E_{ij}(a+b),$$ $$[E_{ij}(a),E_{jk}(a)]=E_{ik}(a) \mbox{ if $i\neq k$,}$$ $$[E_{ij}(a),E_{kl}(b)]=1 \mbox{ if $i\neq l$ and $j\neq k$.}$$
Yet the group presented by generators and this relations is *not* $E(n,A)$, but what we call the $*n$-th unstable Steinberg group* $\mathrm{St}(n, A)$ of $A$. In general, this is larger than (precisely, an extension of) $E(n,A)$.

(**NB:** The following paragraph has been edited to make it match reality. Thanks to Allen for pointing the mistake in the comment bellow)

This is seen, for example, because the map $\mathrm{St}(n, A)\to E(n,A)$ has a non-trivial kernel. Indeed, after passing to the direct limit as $n$ goes to infinity, the kernel of that map is precisely the second algebraic $K$-theory group of $A$, $K_2(A)$. Milnor shows in his book that $K_2(\mathbb{R})$ is uncountable, and describes $K_2(\mathbb Q)$ (he also shows that $K_2(\mathbb Z)$ is cyclic of order two, so this can be done for rings that are not fields too...)

A nice reference for all this is Jonathan Rosenberger's [*Algebraic $K$-theory and its applications*](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1282290), and there is John Milnor's [*Introduction to algebraic $K$-theory*](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0349811), which is also extremely nice.

A short intuitive description for $K_2(A)$ is: it measures how much more information is there in the elementary matrices of a ring which does not follow formally from the Steinberg relations.

Comment: The kernel of the stabilized map $St(\infty,A)\to E(\infty,A)$ is $K_2(A)$, not $K_3(A)$. Milnor showed that $K_2(\mathbb Z)$ is cyclic of order 2.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $R=\mathbb F_2$ is the field with two elements and $n=2$. Then we need not consider the matrices $E_i(a)$, for the only possible $a$ is $1$, so your group is generated by $\alpha=E_{12}$ and $\beta=E_{21}$. Your fourth relation implies that $$\alpha^2=\beta^2=1.$$ Your fifth equation is empty in this case (for it is only meaningful for when $a$ and $b$ are non-zero elements of the field which add up to a non-zero element of the field!) Finally, your sixth relation in this case tells us that $(\alpha\beta\alpha)^2=(\beta\alpha\beta)^2=1$, but these two equalities follow from the previous equation.

We thus see that the group generated by the $E_i(a)$'s and the $E_{ij}$ subject to your relations is, in this case, $$\langle\alpha,\beta:\alpha^2=\beta^2=1\rangle.$$
This is an infinite group, so it is not $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb F_2)$.

Exactly the same reasoning shows that the same happens for all $n\geq 2$: you get free products of cyclic groups of order $2$.

**NB:** It wouldn't be the first time that $\mathbb F_2$ behaves differently from other fields... I doubt that is the case, and surely someone with enough determination will be able to use [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) to check whether the group given by your generators and relations is or not $\mathrm{GL}$, at least for other small fields...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you give Mariano a check mark.  MathOverflow does not function properly when you change a question substantially after it has been correctly answered.

Regarding your revised question, we can fix the presentation by throwing it away and using Steinberg's presentation, which works without problems.  I couldn't find an online copy of his paper, but [this 1971 article](http://www.ams.org/bull/1971-77-02/S0002-9904-1971-12704-0/S0002-9904-1971-12704-0.pdf) describes how to present the R-points of any semisimple simply connected Chevalley-Demazure group, for R any commutative ring.

I have heard that the presentation in the case of the general linear group is due to Schur, but I don't know a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Cohn's paper "On the structure of the ${\rm GL}_{2}$ of a ring", MR0207856.